# Modifying a template based excel in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am tyring to run code like this
xlWorkSheet.Cells(rownumber, 1) = "Some Value"

the problem is when I open the excel document the cell value is not updated.

any help will be appreciated

I use the following code to open the file

```
Dim pathtofile As String = Server.MapPath("~/UserControls/Upload/MyUpload.xlsx")

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application =New Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlworkbooks As Excel.Workbooks
Dim xlWorksheets As Excel.Worksheets
Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing

xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)

xlworkbooks = xlApp.Workbooks

xlWorkBook = xlworkbooks.Open(pathtofile )

xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

Comment: How do you open the doc ? (show us code)

Comment: How about the code that saves and closes the workbook?

Comment: Also, why are you creating an empty workbook as your first action? I'm pretty sure that your `Open` will replace that empty workbook as the active workbook, but updating the empty one instead of the one you open afterwards might explain why your changes are not being saved. I'd get rid of the statement that creates the empty workbook and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save, close, and release the com objects to make sure excel doesn't remain running as a process.

```
Sub save(filename As String) ' Saves the sheet under a specfic name
        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(filename)
    End Sub

 Sub closexl()
        xlWorkBooks.Close()
        xlApp.Quit()
    End Sub

Sub cleanup() ' Releases all of the com objects to object not have excel running as a process after this method finishes
        GC.Collect()
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet)
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook)
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp)
        xlApp = Nothing
    End Sub
```